# Compare two pandas dataframes and update one, depending on results

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following (simplified) data;

```
import pandas as pd

a = [['10', '12345', '4'], ['15', '78910', '3'], ['8', '23456', '10']]
b = [['10', '12345'], ['15', '78910'], ['9', '23456']]

df_a = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['id', 'sku', 'quantity '])
df_b = pd.DataFrame(b, columns =['id','sku'])
```

I need to compare the 'id and 'sku' columns from both dataframes and for those that match I need to update `df_a['quantity']`to equal '0'.

So, something like an if statement?

```
if (df_a['id'] == df_b['id']) and (df_a['sku'] == df_b['sku']):
    df_a['quantity']=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most elegant way, but will do the trick if dataframes have different shapes.

```
a_id_sku = df_a.id + df_a.sku
b_id_sku = df_b.id + df_b.sku

df_a.loc[a_id_sku.isin(b_id_sku), 'quantity '] = 0
```

Let me know if this worked

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
df_a.loc[(df_b['id'] == df_a['id']) & (df_a['sku'] == df_b['sku']), 'quantity '] = 0
```

Comment: That would do it except my dataframes are different shapes. Which throws:  "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects" So, how can this be done with dataframes that have different shapes?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using [pandas merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df_a.loc[pd.merge(df_a, df_b, on = ['id', 'sku'] , how='left',
    indicator=True)['_merge'] == 'both', 'quantity'] = 0

df_a
    id  sku quantity
0   10  12345   0
1   15  78910   0
2   8   23456   10
```