# Pandas Dataframe updating a column based comparing some other columns with the columns of another dataframe with different number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames

df1:  4 columns and 2000 rows

```
   E G H L
0
1
2
3
...
```

df2:  26 columns (can be more later) and unknown rows

```
  A B C D E ... Z
0
1
2
3
...
```

I want to update column L of df2 with the value of column L of df1 in such a way that if the value of columns E G H is the same in df1 and df2.

I tried different solutions I found in Stackoverflow but I got different errors.

For example from based on this Q/A: [Compare two pandas dataframes and update one, depending on results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916333/compare-two-pandas-dataframes-and-update-one-depending-on-results/46916391)

I tried :

```
if df2['E'] == df1['E'] and  df2['G'] == df1['G'] and \
   df2['H'] == df1['h']:
    df2['L'] = df1['L']
```

I got ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

based on [Pandas "Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548370/pandas-can-only-compare-identically-labeled-dataframe-objects-error) I change it to

```
if df2['E'] == df1['E'] and  df2['G'] == df1['G'] and \
   df2['H'] == df1['h'] and df1.reset_index(drop=True) == df2.reset_index(drop=True):
    df2['L'] = df1['L']
```

and I got the same error

Here is more information:
df1 is actually a map and based on the value of the columns E G H I have to find the value of L and put it in the same rows in the column L of df2.
Here is an example:
Assuming that in data frame 1 I have

> E item: RAM, G stock: No-2, H State(Province):NY,  L Part Code:5X456

Now for every row in the data frame 2 that the value of  E item, G stock, and H State is the same as above I need to update  L Part Code to 5X456.

Comment: `identically-labeled Series objects` this error comes because of the unmatched number of rows between df1 and df2. when you perform `df1["E"] == df2["E"]` the rows will not be in same shape in both the sides.

Comment: Maybe help [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples), hard to know answer without sample data in both DataFrames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is use left join only necessary columns (`h` war renamed to `H` for match) with remove original `L` column and added new `df1.L` and last for original order of columns use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df11=df1.rename(columns={'h':'H'})[['E','G','H','L']].drop_duplicates(subset=['E','G','H'])
df2 = (df2.drop(['L'], axis=1)
          .merge(df11, on=['E','G','H'], how='left')
          .reindex(df2.columns, axis=1))
```

Comment: it creates unwanted extra rows. ( I changed on='left' to how='left)

Comment: @G.Hak. - How working if removed duplicated rows?

Comment: the sample I tested has   223 rows after applying the above code I got 297 rows then I used drop_duplicates() and the result was 295 rows so it has extra rows yet.